# Is it valid to mix headings into lists / tables in HTML?

Tags: html, validation, accessibility

I often encounter stuff like this in webpages:

```
<h1>Main heading</h1>

<h2>Sub heading 1</h2>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Sub sub heading 1</h3>
    <p>Some other content</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Sub sub heading 2</h3>
    <p>Some other content</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Sub sub heading 3</h3>
      <p>Some other content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>Sub sub heading 4</h3>
      <h4>Sub sub sub heading 1</h4>
      <p>Some other content</p>
      <h4>Sub sub sub heading 2</h4>
      <p>Some other content</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it valid to mix headings into lists and tables? While a blind friend argues that this is helping him to navigate with the screenreader, this somehow doesn't feel right to me, it breaks the feeling of "linearity".

Comment: That's a misuse of lists and tables. That's not list data. That's not tabular data.

Comment: I agree with you, but can you give me a specification or something that disallows it?

Comment: Nothing *disallows* it, it's just absurdly bad practice.

Comment: Well as far as i know it's valid `html`. But not semantically appropriate, especially the table..

Comment: Re tables: Depending on what technology your friend is using, it may see "Oh this is not a data table" and make all `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` into `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is valid in any version of HTML. Just check the content models of `li` and `td` elements and you will see that headings are allowed.

Whether it is good practice is a different issue, and a matter of opinion. Typically, heading elements inside tables are symptoms of using tables for layout, but there are other cases, too (e.g., a table containing some text in two languages). Heading elements inside `li` elements are usually symptoms of overusing list elements.

Comment: A blind co-worker confirms that there's no need for headings inside tables and lists, as there are other ways to navigate within those elements (independent from headings).